# Compare the data of three column and set the flag in fourth column

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have above table structure, where 1st, 3rd and 5th row are same. There might be many records in the table, but I have used it just as a example. So if the data of Column A, Column B and Column C are same then I have to update Flag column as Yes otherwise No. I'm using SQL Server 2019.

I tried to update the only 'Yes' in the flag column with the following Query:

```
update table set Flag='Yes' where (SELECT Column A, Column B, Column C, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Column A, Column B, Column C HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
```

But getting following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"But it's not working"* When posting a question, you need to *explain* why it's not working. We can't run your SQL, we don't have access to your system nor do have consumable sample data we can use, so "It's not working" doesn't tell us much. If you're getting an error, include it in your question. If you're not getting the results you expect, explain what those results are and why they aren't what you want/what you really want. If you're getting undesired behaviour, tell us what that behaviour is and why is isn't what you want.

Comment: @Larnu, updated the question, sure will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An updatable CTE seems to be what you are after:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Flag,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) AS DupeCount
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Flag = CASE DupeCount WHEN 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by a, b, c) as cnt
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set flag = 'yes'
    where cnt > 1;
```

I would suggest fixing the table so rows are not 100% duplicated -- but perhaps you have other columns that are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Actually that's how data saved into the table and can't change the table structure. I think, required columns shared with question? I appreciate your feedback, thanks.

Comment: @Shatanu . . . Given that your question is only about assigning "yes" to the duplicated rows, I'm surprised you did not accept this answer.

Comment: ,I have specifically mentioned : I have to update Flag column as Yes otherwise No., and even in the screenshot I have updated the same. What I mentioned is I just tried to update 'Yes' with the given query but it's not working but I have to update Yes or No.