# update field from group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2016, let's have the following recordset

[image]

I need to update the "IsSame" field when the tpEndDay is the same for any arbDelivery field.
For example, arbDelivery 76873614 should have IsSame = 0, because tpEndDay is different. 76874450 shoud have IsSame = 1, etc.

How can I do this?

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Please see this for how to ask a good question with proper details.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question  Also do not post screen shots and provide your table structures, examples, and what have you tried?

Comment: A very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67804912/2029983) was asked earlier. The same principle applies here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare the data of three column and set the flag in fourth column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804912/compare-the-data-of-three-column-and-set-the-flag-in-fourth-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend to specify FROM with the same table you UPDATE.

in this case you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE  my_table
SET     IsSame = 
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    my_table AS same
                    WHERE   same.tpEndDay = my_table.tpEndDay
                    AND     same.arbDelivery <> my_table.arbDelivery
                )
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
FROM    my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some sample data. You can change the On clause according to your join condition.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mydatatable](
    [arbNoColis] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [arbDelivery] [int] NULL,
    [tbEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsSame] [bit] NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO
   INSERT [dbo].[mydatatable] ([arbNoColis], [arbDelivery], [tbEndDate], [IsSame]) VALUES (N'wwwwwwwww', 24499002, CAST(N'2021-02-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
GO
   INSERT [dbo].[mydatatable] ([arbNoColis], [arbDelivery], [tbEndDate], [IsSame]) VALUES (N'wwwwwwwww', 244990502, CAST(N'2021-05-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
GO
  INSERT [dbo].[mydatatable] ([arbNoColis], [arbDelivery], [tbEndDate], [IsSame]) VALUES (N'tttttt', 244999002, CAST(N'2021-05-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[mydatatable] ([arbNoColis], [arbDelivery], [tbEndDate], [IsSame]) VALUES (N'tttttt', 222999002, CAST(N'2021-05-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
 GO
 
UPDATEA
    SET A.IsSame = CASE WHEN B.[rowcount] = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM mydatatable A 
INNER JOIN (

        SELECT
            COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY tbEndDate ORDER BY tbEndDate) AS [rowcount]
            ,*
        FROM mydatatable ) AS B 
ON A.arbNoColis = B.arbNoColis AND A.arbDelivery = B.arbDelivery
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `COUNT` window aggregate in a derived table and update directly through the derived table

```sql
UPDATE t
    SET IsSame = CASE WHEN t.cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT *
        cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY arbDelivery)
    FROM YourTable
) t
```